# How do I remove my name from an app that I've uploaded to the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I've uploaded an app to the apple app store and I don't want my name to be publicly visible on the app store, is there any way to replace it with the name of my website?

The only options I've been able to find is to create a new developer account and pay the $99 fee a second time under an account with my website's name and re-upload the app from that account, but I really don't want to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if you are enrolling as an Individual the name of your account should be displayed when you open the app page in App Store , one way is to enroll as an Organization ( **Apple** needs many things for it ) and specify **Legal Entity Name** and it will be displayed instead of your name

Comment: Is there any way to edit one's enrollment to change it from individual to organization?

Comment: Yes, you can i worked for a company that did it , you can contact apple for that and follow their requirements